# I shouldn't say something (not good) about Islam here?

Tags: discussion

Someone asked what is "What is fundamentally unique about Islam", and I saw others answered, but I think one more thing should be mentioned here, Jihad. one of a ten most important duties of Muslims, which also (by my references) has a very great impact on their history.

[What is fundamentally unique about Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-is-fundamentally-unique-about-islam/5906#5906)

But I got downvotes, without any reason, Am I supposed to prove Islam is best possible thing for humans? or is it possible to have some critics in answers with good references (as I provided)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking for things that stand out and that are different from the religions of the world, as mentioned in one answer, Islam is in the middle range between Judaism and Christianity.  Jihad of some sort is in almost all religions (to my knowledge of course).  The question is asking only for the things unique to Islam, and that cannot be found in any other religion.  It is not asking what is the most important and fundamental things in Islam.

Comment: Yes, your reason is logical somehow, but actually Jihad in Islam is really bold, and as I mentioned has a great impact on Muslims history. Anyway, back to my main question, you mean critics are also welcome in Islam site? (I didn't see anything in FAQ to ban this, but one person told me do not do it: 
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/why-must-there-be-a-god/1940#comment11562_1940
Anyway, I'm not after what S/he said, but I'm wonder if criticism is banned here?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Up-voting or down-voting is here to raise or lower the quality of a post, if a post is of good quality it gets up-voted, if it is not, it  is down-voted.